# While loop in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to run while loop in shell

```
 NODESTATE="0"
         LOOPC="1"
            while [ "$NODESTATE" -ne "UP" ]; do

echo "node is up "
```

but it is throwing me an error with [: UP: integer expression expected
or shoud i use != instead of -ne

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your condition:

```
        while [ "$NODESTATE" -ne "UP" ]; do
```

The `-ne` option is used to determine whether one comparator is numerically equal to another. But you're doing a string comparison, not a numeric one.  Instead, try the following:

```
        while [ "$NODESTATE" != "UP" ]; do
```

You can read [`man test`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=test) to see how the various options to `[` work.